# Inserting a tab character into a textarea while modifying editing history

Tags: javascript

It is easy to add a tab character into a textarea (using el.value, el.selectionStart, el.selectionEnd), but I haven't been able to insert this change into the textarea's editing (undo) history.

Is this possible?